# javascript code is not working as Userscript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, tampermonkey, userscripts

i need to get the background url by clicking on a button
the code is working as you see here
https://jsfiddle.net/iN4sser/Lpru4hgd/3/
but if i used it as userscript in tampermonkey or Violentmonkey it doesn't work, the result "undefined"
the userscript

```js
// ==UserScript==
// @name        Background Url
// @namespace   Violentmonkey Scripts
// @include       *://*jsfiddle.*/*
// @grant          GM_setValue
// @grant        GM_xmlhttpRequest
// @grant          GM_getValue
// @grant       GM_addStyle
// @version     1.0
// @author      -
// @description 6/5/2020, 11:31:32 AM
// ==/UserScript==
(function() {
  window.addEventListener("load", () => {
    addButton("Get Url");
  });
var img = document.getElementsByClassName('vjs-poster'),
  style = img.currentStyle || window.getComputedStyle(img[0], false),
  bi = style.backgroundImage.slice(4, -1).replace(/"/g, '');
  function addButton(text, onclick, cssObj) {
    cssObj = cssObj || {
      position: "fixed",
      top: "15%",
      right: "4%",
      "z-index": 3,
      fontWeight: "600",
      fontSize: "14px",
      backgroundColor: "#00cccc",
      color: "white",
      border: "none",
      padding: "10px 20px"
    };
    let button = document.createElement("button"),
      btnStyle = button.style;
    document.body.appendChild(button);
    button.innerHTML = text;
    // Settin function for button when it is clicked.
    button.onclick = selectReadFn;
    Object.keys(cssObj).forEach(key => (btnStyle[key] = cssObj[key]));
    return button;
  }

  function selectReadFn() {
    var txt = document.getElementsByClassName("vjs-poster");
    // Just to show button is pressed
    alert('Image URL: ' + bi);
  }
})();
```

Comment: Why `img.currentStyle` and not `img[0].currentStyle`? Where do you see `undefined`? Do we need to see all 48 lines of code or is there a more minimal code snippet that reproduces the issue? Have you checked your browser console (which should also show output for user-scripts) for errors?

Comment: i don't know much about javascript, this is what i get "https://i.imgur.com/cGuBqAv.gifv" there is no output in the console

Comment: There is no `.vjs-poster` element on the JSFiddle site. It’s only inside your snippet beyond an `<iframe>` which runs under `https://fiddle.jshell.net`. You’d need to find out how to run your user-scripts within `<iframe>`s … and fix the `img.currentStyle` … and stop execution if `img[0]` is `undefined`.